# How to get IntPtr to a boolean value

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling

For a function marshalled like that:

```
/*************************************************
*  DWORD WINAPI WlanHostedNetworkSetProperty(
*      _In_        HANDLE hClientHandle,
*      _In_        _WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_OPCODE OpCode,
*      _In_        DWORD dwDataSize,
*      _In_        PVOID pvData,
*      _Out_opt_   P_WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_REASON pFailReason,
*      _Reserved_  PVOID pvReserved
*  );
*************************************************/
[DllImport("Wlanapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern UInt32 WlanHostedNetworkSetProperty(
    [In] IntPtr hClientHandle,
    [In] _WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_OPCODE OpCode,
    [In] UInt32 dwDataSize,
    [In] IntPtr pvData,
    [Out] out _WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_REASON pFailReason,
    [In, Out] IntPtr pvReserved
);
```

Microsoft documentation says that when I pass

```
_WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_OPCODE._WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_OPCODE_enable
```

as a parameter of **OpCode**, the value of **pvData** should be a pointer to a Boolean value.
[Hereis the documentation for that function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd439495%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
I have no idea though how to get an IntPtr to point to a Boolean?
Should it be done in a similar way to when I pass a pointer to a struct as **pvData** :

```
int size = Marshal.SizeOf(settings); //*settings* is a struct with some data
IntPtr pSettings = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
Marshal.StructureToPtr(settings, pSettings, true);

/* use the IntPtr */

Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pSettings);
```

But instead I marshal the Boolean? Or is there an easier way?

Thanks for your help all lovely people.

Comment: How did you set up your structures for the settings?(DOT11_SSID and WLAN_HOSTED...) Do you mind updating the question with the code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Win32 BOOL is DWORD. You can define pvData as `ref UInt32` or `ref Int32` for this case. Or leave pvData as IntPtr, allocate unmanaged memory with `Marshal.AllocHGLobal(Marshal.SizeOf(Int32))`, and fill this memory with `Marshal.WriteInt32`.

```
int size = Marshal.SizeOf(Int32);
IntPtr pBool = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
Marshal.WriteInt32(pBool, 0, 1);  // last parameter 0 (FALSE), 1 (TRUE)

/* use the IntPtr */

Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pBool);
```

Answer (score 7):

Oh, yes, there's a much easier way.  This can be very elegantly done in C# because it supports method overloading.  A feature that doesn't exist in C and thus requires the PVOID argument type.  You can simply declare the argument as `ref bool`.  The marshaller will create the storage for the BOOL before calling the native function and pass a pointer to it.  Converting and copying the result back into the bool variable you pass after the call.

If you have additional calls for this function that require a different data type then just repeat the declaration.  This time specifying, say, `ref uint` if you are supposed to pass a pointer to a DWORD.  Etcetera.  The C# compiler's method overload resolution feature ensures that the correct pinvoke declaration is used.

Comment: I think that `out` is not enough: "The opcode used to query or set the wireless Hosted Network enabled flag", possibly `ref` is better. The idea of overloading PInvoke functions is cool.